# error: invalid use of void expression

Tags: c++

En este código me salta el siguiente `error: invalid use of void expression.`
Mas precisamente en el `return ciclo_Euleriano(g, g.getVertices().pop_front(), g.getVertices().pop_front());` y no se porque motivo es.

```
bool ciclo_Euleriano(const Grafo<T> & g, T u, T first) { //u es el vertice
    bool found = false;
    if (!aristas.empty()) {
        list<typename Grafo<T>::Arco> adyacentes = g.getAdyacentes(u);
        for (typename list<typename Grafo<T>::Arco>::iterator it = adyacentes.begin(); it != adyacentes.end() && !found; it++) {
            if (Camino_no_Usado(u, it->getAdyacente(), aristas)) {
                addArista(camino, u, it->getAdyacente(), g.getCosto(u, *it));
                eliminar(u, *it, aristas);
                found = ciclo_Euleriano(g, *it, first);
                if (!found) {
                    addArista(aristas, u, *it, g.getCosto(u, *it));
                    camino.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }
    } else
        if (u == first)
            found = true;
    return found;
}

bool ciclo_Euleriano(const Grafo<T> & g) {
    list<typename Grafo<T>::Arco> aristas = g.getAristas();
    camino.clear();
    return ciclo_Euleriano(g, g.getVertices().pop_front(), g.getVertices().pop_front());
}
```

Por aca dejo el `getVertices()`:

```
list<T> getVertices() const {
    list<T> vertices;
    for (typename map<T, map<T, int> >::const_iterator itV = grafo.begin(); itV != grafo.end(); itV++)
        vertices.push_front(itV->first);
    return vertices;
}
```

Comment: Modrias mostrarnos la definicion de `getVertices()`?

Comment: @IkerObregonReigosa ya está.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tipo `void` por definición es un tipo incompleto, que no puede ser completado. No puede formar parte de expresiones ni se puede instanciar.

Tú estás llamando a la función `ciclo_Euleriano` pasándole el resultado de llamar a dos funciones que devuelven `void`.

Dado que `Grafo<T>::getVertices` devuelve una `std::list`, podemos ver que la función `pop_front` devuelve `void`:

- [`std::list::pop_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front).

Seguramente lo que querías era obtener las cabezas (*front*) llamar a `ciclo_Euleriano` y luego eliminar el elemento de cabeza:

```
bool ciclo_Euleriano(const Grafo<T> & g) {
    const auto &aristas = g.getAristas();
    auto v = g.getVertices().front();

    camino.clear();
    g.getVertices().pop_front();

    return ciclo_Euleriano(g, v, v);
}
```

---

Como nota adicional, tu código mejoraría mucho en legibilidad usando `auto` y algunas utilidades de C++:

```
list<T> getVertices() const {
    list<T> vertices;

    std::copy(grafo.begin(), grafo.end(), std::front_inserter(vertices));
    return vertices;
}
```